# Why does this gpg in golang command return a No Such File Or Directory error on windows when attempting to encrypt a temporary file?

Tags: go, gnupg, cobra

This function works fine on linux but for some reason on windows it always returns a file not found error pointing to the location of the temporary file. If i get the temporary file by its name and read it before encryption, the read is successful and correct, but when the encrypt command runs it returns the error. Also when i run the exact command that gpg is running it completes successfully.

OS: Windows 10
GPG: Gpg4win 4.1.0

Below is an excerpt from my code

```
func createTempFile(dir, prefix string) (*os.File, error) {
    tmpfile, err := os.CreateTemp(dir, prefix)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return tmpfile, nil
}

func writeFile(filename string, data []byte, perm os.FileMode) error {
    file, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, perm)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    _, err = file.Write(data)
    return err
}
func (g *GPGModule) Encrypt(plaintext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    tmpfile, err := createTempFile("", "gpg-encrypt-")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer os.Remove(tmpfile.Name())

    err = writeFile(tmpfile.Name(), plaintext, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    outputFile := fmt.Sprintf("%s.gpg", tmpfile.Name())
    defer os.Remove(outputFile)

    cmd := exec.Command(g.GPGPath, "--encrypt", "--armor", "--recipient", g.GPGID, "--output", outputFile, tmpfile.Name())
    errOutput, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("GPG encryption failed: %v\nError Output: %s", err, string(errOutput))
    }

    return readFile(outputFile)
}
```

Please help me fix this as I am new to golang and am struggling with this error

I have tried everything i can think of and everything that pops up on google, nothing seems to be able to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The file not found error on windows is because you are using exec.Command to run this gpg exe but there's no reason to do this:

https://github.com/andrewarrow/clout-cli/blob/c17af37d539839979b8e94828f21e7895578d3ab/session/encryption.go#L18

Go has nice libs to encrypt built in so you can avoid shelling out:

```
import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the main reason I was using GNUpg in the first place was to have non-proprietary encryption and to allow for the encrypted files to be used without my specific program. Would there be any way to still use GNUpg or perhaps use those encryption libraries in a non-proprietary manner?

Comment: oh sure, your cmd := exec.Command(g.GPGPath, "--encrypt", "--armor", "--recipient", g.GPGID, "--output", outputFile, tmpfile.Name()) can work if you just get the g.GPGPath, outputFile, tmpfile.Name() parts named/escaped right for windows. Sounds like they need \ instead of / or escaping a space in the name, something like that.